# Ethernet connection disables WIFI

Tags: routing, wifi, ethernet, dnsmasq

Our company makes a 3d printer built around a Jetson Nano. The printer connects to the internet using a wifi dongle, but for the initial setup the user must connect to the printer using an ethernet connection to one of their devices.  The printer is running dnsmasq-base so that when the user navigates to http:// they can access the server and do the configuration.

The problem is that when they connect to the jetsonNano via ethernet it disables the Wifi on their host device. And routes all traffic through the printer! and until the printer's wifi is setup they lose all connectivity.

Ideally we want a solution that allows the user to setup the printer via a wired connection, that doesn't require the user to make any configuration changes on their device.

From the documentation for dnsmasq.conf I have tried

```
dhcp-range=192.168.0.1,proxy
```

but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I've copied below the routing tables:

Routing tables With Ethernet Connected:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            10.42.2.1          UGScg             en0       
default            192.168.0.1        UGScIg            en1       
10.42.2/24         link#6             UCS               en0      !
10.42.2.1/32       link#6             UCS               en0      !
10.42.2.1          48:b0:2d:55:9a:2   UHLWIir           en0   1178
10.42.2.31/32      link#6             UCS               en0      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0       
169.254            link#6             UCS               en0      !
169.254            link#13            UCSI              en1      !
192.168.0          link#13            UCS               en1      !
192.168.0.1/32     link#13            UCS               en1      !
192.168.0.1        84:94:8c:c3:5a:c2  UHLWIir           en1   1184
192.168.0.26/32    link#13            UCS               en1      !
192.168.0.26       14:98:77:69:2b:52  UHLWI             lo0       
192.168.0.28       54:60:9:b8:8b:a2   UHLWIi            en1    775
192.168.0.29       1c:bf:ce:69:6c:8f  UHLWI             en1   1173
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS              en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#13            UmCSI             en1      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI            en1       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI            en0       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI            en1       
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS               en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#13            UCSI              en1      !

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags           Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcIg           utun0       
default                                 fe80::%utun1                    UGcIg           utun1       
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcIg           utun2       
::1                                     ::1                             UHL               lo0       
fc00::/7                                fe80::8694:8cff:fec3:5ac2%en1   UGc               en1       
fd00:8494:8cc3:5ac2::/64                link#13                         UC                en1       
fd00:8494:8cc3:5ac2:1c34:bcef:8dbd:3cf4 14:98:77:69:2b:52               UHL               lo0       
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI               lo0       
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%anpi0/64                         link#4                          UCI             anpi0       
fe80::f475:7bff:fe58:8642%anpi0         f6:75:7b:58:86:42               UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%anpi1/64                         link#5                          UCI             anpi1       
fe80::f475:7bff:fe58:8643%anpi1         f6:75:7b:58:86:43               UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%en0/64                           link#6                          UCI               en0       
fe80::1ca0:231b:2a4b:e1ea%en0           14:98:77:70:b1:7a               UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%en1/64                           link#13                         UCI               en1       
fe80::105e:139:9e45:390f%en1            14:98:77:69:2b:52               UHLI              lo0       
fe80::8694:8cff:fec3:5ac2%en1           84:94:8c:c3:5a:c2               UHLWIi            en1       
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#15                         UCI             awdl0       
fe80::4c4c:15ff:fe96:990a%awdl0         4e:4c:15:96:99:a                UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%llw0/64                          link#16                         UCI              llw0       
fe80::4c4c:15ff:fe96:990a%llw0          4e:4c:15:96:99:a                UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%utun0/64                         fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0 UcI             utun0       
fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0         link#17                         UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%utun1/64                         fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1 UcI             utun1       
fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1         link#18                         UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%utun2/64                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2   UcI             utun2       
fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2           link#19                         UHLI              lo0       
ff00::/8                                ::1                             UmCI              lo0       
ff00::/8                                link#4                          UmCI            anpi0       
ff00::/8                                link#5                          UmCI            anpi1       
ff00::/8                                link#6                          UmCI              en0       
ff00::/8                                link#13                         UmCI              en1       
ff00::/8                                link#15                         UmCI            awdl0       
ff00::/8                                link#16                         UmCI             llw0       
ff00::/8                                fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0 UmCI            utun0       
ff00::/8                                fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1 UmCI            utun1       
ff00::/8                                fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2   UmCI            utun2       
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI              lo0       
ff01::%anpi0/32                         link#4                          UmCI            anpi0       
ff01::%anpi1/32                         link#5                          UmCI            anpi1       
ff01::%en0/32                           link#6                          UmCI              en0       
ff01::%en1/32                           link#13                         UmCI              en1       
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#15                         UmCI            awdl0       
ff01::%llw0/32                          link#16                         UmCI             llw0       
ff01::%utun0/32                         fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0 UmCI            utun0       
ff01::%utun1/32                         fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1 UmCI            utun1       
ff01::%utun2/32                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2   UmCI            utun2       
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI              lo0       
ff02::%anpi0/32                         link#4                          UmCI            anpi0       
ff02::%anpi1/32                         link#5                          UmCI            anpi1       
ff02::%en0/32                           link#6                          UmCI              en0       
ff02::%en1/32                           link#13                         UmCI              en1       
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#15                         UmCI            awdl0       
ff02::%llw0/32                          link#16                         UmCI             llw0       
ff02::%utun0/32                         fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0 UmCI            utun0       
ff02::%utun1/32                         fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1 UmCI            utun1       
ff02::%utun2/32                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2   UmCI            utun2
```

Without ETH connected:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGScg             en1       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS               lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                lo0       
169.254            link#13            UCS               en1      !
192.168.0          link#13            UCS               en1      !
192.168.0.1/32     link#13            UCS               en1      !
192.168.0.1        84:94:8c:c3:5a:c2  UHLWIir           en1   1195
192.168.0.26/32    link#13            UCS               en1      !
192.168.0.26       14:98:77:69:2b:52  UHLWI             lo0       
192.168.0.28       54:60:9:b8:8b:a2   UHLWIi            en1   1196
192.168.0.29       1c:bf:ce:69:6c:8f  UHLWIi            en1   1195
224.0.0/4          link#13            UmCS              en1      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI            en1       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI            en1       
255.255.255.255/32 link#13            UCS               en1      !

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags           Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcIg           utun0       
default                                 fe80::%utun1                    UGcIg           utun1       
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcIg           utun2       
::1                                     ::1                             UHL               lo0       
fc00::/7                                fe80::8694:8cff:fec3:5ac2%en1   UGc               en1       
fd00:8494:8cc3:5ac2::/64                link#13                         UC                en1       
fd00:8494:8cc3:5ac2:1c34:bcef:8dbd:3cf4 14:98:77:69:2b:52               UHL               lo0       
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI               lo0       
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%anpi0/64                         link#4                          UCI             anpi0       
fe80::f475:7bff:fe58:8642%anpi0         f6:75:7b:58:86:42               UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%anpi1/64                         link#5                          UCI             anpi1       
fe80::f475:7bff:fe58:8643%anpi1         f6:75:7b:58:86:43               UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%en1/64                           link#13                         UCI               en1       
fe80::105e:139:9e45:390f%en1            14:98:77:69:2b:52               UHLI              lo0       
fe80::8694:8cff:fec3:5ac2%en1           84:94:8c:c3:5a:c2               UHLWIi            en1       
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#15                         UCI             awdl0       
fe80::4c4c:15ff:fe96:990a%awdl0         4e:4c:15:96:99:a                UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%llw0/64                          link#16                         UCI              llw0       
fe80::4c4c:15ff:fe96:990a%llw0          4e:4c:15:96:99:a                UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%utun0/64                         fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0 UcI             utun0       
fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0         link#17                         UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%utun1/64                         fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1 UcI             utun1       
fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1         link#18                         UHLI              lo0       
fe80::%utun2/64                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2   UcI             utun2       
fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2           link#19                         UHLI              lo0       
ff00::/8                                ::1                             UmCI              lo0       
ff00::/8                                link#4                          UmCI            anpi0       
ff00::/8                                link#5                          UmCI            anpi1       
ff00::/8                                link#6                          UmCI              en0       
ff00::/8                                link#13                         UmCI              en1       
ff00::/8                                link#15                         UmCI            awdl0       
ff00::/8                                link#16                         UmCI             llw0       
ff00::/8                                fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0 UmCI            utun0       
ff00::/8                                fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1 UmCI            utun1       
ff00::/8                                fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2   UmCI            utun2       
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI              lo0       
ff01::%anpi0/32                         link#4                          UmCI            anpi0       
ff01::%anpi1/32                         link#5                          UmCI            anpi1       
ff01::%en0/32                           link#6                          UmCI              en0       
ff01::%en1/32                           link#13                         UmCI              en1       
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#15                         UmCI            awdl0       
ff01::%llw0/32                          link#16                         UmCI             llw0       
ff01::%utun0/32                         fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0 UmCI            utun0       
ff01::%utun1/32                         fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1 UmCI            utun1       
ff01::%utun2/32                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2   UmCI            utun2       
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI              lo0       
ff02::%anpi0/32                         link#4                          UmCI            anpi0       
ff02::%anpi1/32                         link#5                          UmCI            anpi1       
ff02::%en0/32                           link#6                          UmCI              en0       
ff02::%en1/32                           link#13                         UmCI              en1       
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#15                         UmCI            awdl0       
ff02::%llw0/32                          link#16                         UmCI             llw0       
ff02::%utun0/32                         fe80::a66b:2336:f54b:b872%utun0 UmCI            utun0       
ff02::%utun1/32                         fe80::3390:e111:6ec6:ec21%utun1 UmCI            utun1       
ff02::%utun2/32                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2   UmCI            utun2
```

Comment: I haven't observed this on Linux, but it is a semi-common security "feature" on Windows (disable WLAN on LAN). I've also seen some hardware vendors (HP) that offer similar OS-agnostic functionality.

Comment: I think that what I want to do is to have the ethernet connected printer piggyback onto the host device's network-- rather than setting itself up as a gateway at  10.42.2.1. -- is that somehow possible while still resolving dns queries at http://<hostname>

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when they connect to the jetsonNano via ethernet it disables the Wifi on their host device. And routes all traffic through the printer! and until the printer's wifi is setup they lose all connectivity.

By default, `dnsmasq` reports the host on which it is running as the default route. That means when your clients connect to the jetsonNano, it becomes their default route -- and since it's not actually connected to anything else, it becomes a black whole.

The solution may be as simple as telling `dnsmasq` to not advertise a default route:

```
dhcp-option=option:router
dhcp-option=option:dns-server
```

This tells `dnsmasq` to not advertise itself as either a default gateway or dns server.

---

Note that you will still have a problem if your clients are using 192.168.0.0/24 as their local network. Since 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.0.0/24 are both reasonably common, consider using something else for your configuration network.